# Namespace in SOAP in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

I'm using the `Savon` gem to interact with a `WSDL`. For some reason, `Savon` is using `env` as a namespace instead of `soapenv`.

How do I make `Savon` generate requests with the `soapenv` namespace, rather than the `env` namespace?

Answer (score 1):

```
Savon.config.env_namespace = :soapenv
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special property for this:

```
Savon.env_namespace = :soapenv
```

With this property set Savon will generate requests like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                    xmlns:wsdl="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
                                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <wsdl:sayHello></wsdl:sayHello>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```